# What's the better way to get the Node.js app total time execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, execution-time

I've made a `Node.js` app that makes exactly the same thing that another solution in `C#`. The both app get all the javascript files from a directory recursively and execute `uglify-js` command to *minify* the files.

**My project has about 150 JavaScript files to minify and the `C#` approach takes about 22s to do all the stuff (using *threads*).**

After reading Node.js documentation and books, I've decided to do the `Node.js` way. I've already did that but I can't do reporting total time `Node.js` do the stuff because its asynchronous approach...

*(yeah, I know, I use threads in `C#` that was asynchronous too)*

So, what's the better way to get the Node.js app total time execution?

I'm using `Node.js v0.10.13` as as `win32` environment.

Comment: Your total execution time is however long it takes to get it all done.  Doing something async doesn't mean it gets done any faster.  Or, are you running sub-processes?  Node.js doesn't do threading (for your JS), so what specifically do you want to measure?

Comment: Yes @Brad. I'm running subprocesses and want to know the total time execution of all of them, when the node.js app returns to command...

Comment: You could just measure the time the process ran, unless you are looking for CPU time?

Comment: If you need CPU time:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7774034/362536

Comment: Can anyone explain why `process.uptime()` doesn't work?

Comment: One reason might be if some bootstrapping need to be done that you don't want included in the total time. But I would think it should work in this case.

Comment: No no @MorganARRAllen, I want the complete time of the process...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the very start of your script, use `console.time('Some_Name_Here');`, and then use `console.timeEnd('Some_Name_Here');` wherever the script finishes its execution.

It's a quick, native functionality of Node.js, and prevents you from having to initialize a new Date object.

Here's some short documentation on the `console.time()` method: http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_time_label.

Comment: Thank you @Bagavatu, but my app has various asynchronous functions with `child_process` and I don't know where to call `console.timeEnd`. Is there a global end event for that?

Comment: I found [process Event: 'exit'](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_event_exit) and `console.time()` works as well!

Answer (score 3):

You could do the time start/end timing method.

At the beginning of your main script you grab the time.

```
var start = Date.now();

process.on("exit", function() {
  var end = Date.now();
  console.log("Time taken: %ds", (end - start)/1000);
});

// all you code...
// more code...
```

Comment: please use `process.hrtime()` instead of `Date`

Comment: Right.. the concept remains the same but cr0 is right, its more accurate in this case. See http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime

Comment: You might also want to use process.uptime() but I cannot speak to its accuracy.