# Get/View Memory & CPU usage via NodeJS

Tags: node.js, npm

I see there are several node packages that allow you to look up a specific process's usage, such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/usage

I am trying to get the overall sever usage/stats (CPU and Memory), not just one specific process or another. Maybe even disk space usage.

I am currently unable to find anything like this, is this possible?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The native module [os](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) can give you some memory and cpu usage statistics.

```
var os = require('os');

console.log(os.cpus());
console.log(os.totalmem());
console.log(os.freemem())
```

The cpus() function gives you an average, but you can calculate the current usage by using a formula and an interval, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565912/convert-the-output-of-os-cpus-in-node-js-to-percentage) answer.

There is also a package that does this for you, called [os-utils](https://github.com/oscmejia/os-utils).

Taken from the example on github:

```
var os = require('os-utils');

os.cpuUsage(function(v){
    console.log( 'CPU Usage (%): ' + v );
});
```

For information about the disk you can use [diskspace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskspace)

Comment: looks like os-utils shows node process info, not overall

Answer (score 24):

Check [node-os-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-os-utils)

- CPU average usage
- Free and used drive space
- Free and used memory space
- Operating System
- All processes running
- TTY/SSH opened
- Total opened files
- Network speed (input and output)

> ```
> var osu = require('node-os-utils')
>
> var cpu = osu.cpu
>
> cpu.usage()
>   .then(info => {
>     console.log(info)
>   })
> ```

Answer (score 5):

As I found no code to solve this problem and don't want to rely on other packages just for some lines of code, I wrote a function that calculates the average CPU load between two successive function calls. I am assuming `t_idle + t_user + t_sys = total cpu time` and results are kind of similar to the ones of my Windows task manager, however, the usage seems little more sensitive to me (e.g. music playback increases the cpu load more than in the Windows task manager). Please corret me if my assumptions are wrong.

```
const os = require('os');

// Initial value; wait at little amount of time before making a measurement.
let timesBefore = os.cpus().map(c => c.times);

// Call this function periodically e.g. using setInterval, 
function getAverageUsage() {
    let timesAfter = os.cpus().map(c => c.times);
    let timeDeltas = timesAfter.map((t, i) => ({
        user: t.user - timesBefore[i].user,
        sys: t.sys - timesBefore[i].sys,
        idle: t.idle - timesBefore[i].idle
    }));

    timesBefore = timesAfter;

    return timeDeltas
        .map(times => 1 - times.idle / (times.user + times.sys + times.idle))
        .reduce((l1, l2) => l1 + l2) / timeDeltas.length;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Node.js has `os.loadavg()` method

```
// Require os module
const os = require('os');

// Printing os.loadavg() value
var avg_load = os.loadavg();

console.log("Load average (1 minute):"
            + String(avg_load[0]));

console.log("Load average (5 minute):"
            + String(avg_load[1]));

console.log("Load average (15 minute):"
            + String(avg_load[2]));
```

More info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-os-loadavg-method/)

Comment: Note: The load average is a Unix-specific concept. On Windows, the return value is always [0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `process.cpuUsage()` to return the system and user cpu time in microseconds. It can also calculate the difference to a previous call.

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cpuusage_previousvalue

Comment: How do you use those values to calculate a percentage?

Comment: @cst1992 I did not need to calculate percentage. You may find an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773826/how-to-find-out-the-cpu-usage-for-node-js-process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good library : [systeminformation](https://systeminformation.io/)
[npm systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation)
This library provides system information like : CPU, Memory, battery, graphics, operating system, file system and more and on several OS : Windows , Linux, Sun, Mac ..

Answer (score -1):

```
async function getinfo() {
 const cpu = await si.cpu();
 const disk = (await si.diskLayout())[0];
 const os = await si.osInfo();
 const versions = await si.versions();
 const ram = await si.mem();

 // CPU Info
 let info = `CPU: ${cpu.manufacturer} ${cpu.brand} ${cpu.speed}GHz\n`;
 info += `Cores: ${cpu.cores} (${cpu.physicalCores} Physical)\n`;

 // RAM Info
 const totalRam = Math.round(ram.total / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
 info += `RAM: ${totalRam}GB\n`;

 // Disk Info
 const size = Math.round(disk.size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024);
 info += `Disk: ${disk.vendor} ${disk.name} ${size}GB ${disk.type} (${disk.interfaceType})\n`;

 //OS Info
 info += `OS: ${os.distro} ${os.codename} (${os.platform})\n`;
 info += `Kernel: ${os.kernel} ${os.arch}\n`;

 // Node Info
 info += `Node: v${versions.node}\n`;
 info += `V8: ${versions.v8}`;
 return info;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `si`?

Comment: @MichaelYaworski let's just assume that stands for `system information`.

`const si = require("os")`

Answer (score -19):

Of course it is possible. But you'll need a C++ native module to do that. And keep in mind that every OS has their own way of querying system resource usage.

For example, if you're on Windows (which might be what you're looking for since `usage` doesn't support Windows), you could do something like

performance.cpp

```
#include <node.h>
#include "performance_algorithm.hpp"

using namespace v8;

void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
    PerformanceAlgorithm::Initialize();
    PerformanceAlgorithm::RegisterMethod(exports);
}

NODE_MODULE(Performance, InitAll)
```

performance_algorithm.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>

#include "baton.hpp"
#include "structs.hpp"
#include "performance_algorithm.hpp"

void PerformanceAlgorithm::Initialize() {
    PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
    PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
}

void PerformanceAlgorithm::RegisterMethod(Handle<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "getPerformanceData", PerformanceAlgorithm::GetPerformanceDataAsync);
}

void PerformanceAlgorithm::GetPerformanceDataAsync(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    if (args.Length() != 1) {
        isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
    } else {
        if (!args[0]->IsFunction()) {
            isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments type")));
        } else {
            Local<Function> callbackFunction = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

            Baton<string, PerformanceData>* baton = new Baton<string, PerformanceData>();
            baton->request.data = baton;
            baton->callbackFunction.Reset(isolate, callbackFunction);

            uv_queue_work(uv_default_loop(), &baton->request, PerformanceAlgorithm::GetPerformanceDataWork, PerformanceAlgorithm::GetPerformanceDataAsyncAfter);
        }
    }
}

void PerformanceAlgorithm::GetPerformanceDataWork(uv_work_t* request) {
    Baton<string, PerformanceData>* baton = static_cast<Baton<string, PerformanceData>*>(request->data);

    baton->result.memory_info.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&baton->result.memory_info);

    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
    baton->result.cpu_usage = counterVal.doubleValue;

    DWORD processIDs[1024], bytesReturned;
    EnumProcesses(processIDs, sizeof(processIDs), &bytesReturned);

    DWORD numberOfProcesses = bytesReturned / sizeof(DWORD);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcesses; i++) {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processIDs[i]);

        HMODULE hMods[1024];
        DWORD cbNeeded;
        if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); j++) {
                TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
                GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[j], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR));

                ProcessInfo info;
                info.process_id = processIDs[i];
                info.path = string(szModName);

                baton->result.processes.push_back(info);

                break;
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }

    sort(baton->result.processes.begin(), baton->result.processes.end(), [](ProcessInfo a, ProcessInfo b) -> bool {
        return a.process_id < b.process_id;
    });

    GetPerformanceInfo(&baton->result.performance_info, sizeof(PERFORMACE_INFORMATION));
}

void PerformanceAlgorithm::GetPerformanceDataAsyncAfter(uv_work_t* request, int status) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    EscapableHandleScope escapableHandleScope(isolate);

    Baton<string, PerformanceData>* baton = static_cast<Baton<string, PerformanceData>*>(request->data);
    Local<Function> callbackFunction = Local<Function>::New(isolate, baton->callbackFunction);

    Local<Object> returnValue = Object::New(isolate);
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "cpu_usage"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.cpu_usage));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "ram_usage"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.dwMemoryLoad));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "total_physical_memory"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.ullTotalPhys));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "available_physical_memory"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.ullAvailPhys));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "total_page_file"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.ullTotalPageFile));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "available_page_file"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.ullAvailPageFile));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "total_virtual"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.ullTotalVirtual));
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "available_virtual"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.memory_info.ullAvailVirtual));

    Local<Array> processes = Array::New(isolate, baton->result.processes.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < baton->result.processes.size(); i++) {
        Local<Object> processInfo = Object::New(isolate);
        processInfo->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "process_id"), Number::New(isolate, baton->result.processes[i].process_id));
        processInfo->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "path"), String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, baton->result.processes[i].path.c_str()));

        processes->Set(i, processInfo);
    }
    returnValue->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "running_processes"), processes);

    const unsigned int argc = 1;
    Handle<Value> argv[argc] = { escapableHandleScope.Escape(returnValue) };
    callbackFunction->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);

    baton->callbackFunction.Reset();
    delete baton;
}
```

Comment: It is possible to do this in node.js natively. Creating a separate application in another language is not a good solution when a node module exists that solves the problem

Comment: answering a JS question with a C++ program is definitely daring :D

Comment: @UnstableEagle : I do not agree with you. Although this answer does not directly answer the question, it will still help others. Isn't it one of the advantages of posting questions and posting answers on public bulletin boards to get unexpected questions and unexpected answers?

Comment: @UnstableEagle the nodejs os module is really bugged. Not reliable for a production use case where you target a cross platform environment.
Look at this issue for example: the os.freemem() is totally screwed on Linux. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23892
Anyway C++ can be used with node-gyp to bind native code to a js module. Definitely an alternative way.