# How can I check how many CPUs and memory my vm instance uses in google-cloud using node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, instance

I can't find how to see the number of CPUs and memory used in a VM instance of google-cloud.
I'm trying to write a function that checks all of my running VM instances and stop every instance that uses more CPUs or memory than limited (depends)

I've created an instance on google-cloud-platform and I want to create a function that runs manually by me that will check if any of the instances is over the limit. How can I check a specific VMs' details?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823972/5979775

Comment: @Avraham in your answer they explain how to see your own statistics. I'm trying to check stats on a virtual machine instance that is created via google-cloud using node.js

Comment: I think you can try [this] (https://medium.com/google-cloud/manage-google-compute-engine-with-node-js-eef8e7a111b4) with the commands which refers @Avraham.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
'use strict';
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();

async function getVms() {
  const vms = await compute.getVMs();
  return vms;
}
exports.main = async () => {
  const vms = await getVms().catch(console.error);
  if (vms) console.log(JSON.stringify(vms, null, 2));
  return vms;
};
if (module === require.main) {
  exports.main(console.log);
}
```

Don't forget to install `npm install @google-cloud/compute`.

In the response, you have all the properties of your VMs.
Look at the machine_type:

```
"machineType": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT>/zones/<ZONE>/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
```

You can also check the custom VM

```
"machineType": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT>/zones/<ZONE>/machineTypes/custom-4-5120",
```

`custom-4-5120` means 4vCPU and 5Gb of memory

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helped me to get to the solution! I just cut the part with the name at the end, filtered the machineType array to find it and see the cpu and memory from the compute.getMachineTypes()