# Posting memory utilization metrics of aws instance by using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I want to get Memory utilization metrics' data of aws instance on my project using nodeJs but i found out that memory Utilization metrics is not a default metrics so i have tried what's given on this page - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html and it worked as shown in figure [memory Utilization metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNgZw.png) but i want to know how to post this metric using nodeJs.

This is the params i have written while using putMetricData -

```
AWS.config.update({ region: 'ap-south-1' });
var instanceId = 'i-096d2fed45f9ee1'
var params = {
    MetricData: [ /* required */
      {
        MetricName: 'MemoryUtilization', /* required */
        // Counts: [
        //   'NUMBER_VALUE',
        //   /* more items */
        // ],
        Dimensions: [
          {
            Name: 'InstanceId', /* required */
            Value: instanceId /* required */
          },
          /* more items */
        ],
        StatisticValues: {
          Maximum: 100, /* required */
          Minimum: 5, /* required */
          SampleCount: 1, /* required */
          Sum: 5 /* required */
        },
        // Timestamp: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
        // Unit: Percent,
        // Value: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
        // Values: [
        //   'NUMBER_VALUE',
        //   /* more items */
        // ]
      },
      /* more items */
    ],
    Namespace: 'System/Linux' /* required */
};
cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Metrics", JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```

I didn't get any error but value of memory utilization are coming like this as shown in image - [memory Util metrics after posting through putMetricsData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwJdL.png) which is not correct if you see [memory Utilization metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNgZw.png) generated by CloudWatch monitoring scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [CloudWatch NodeJS SDK and calling the PutMetricData API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#putMetricData-property).

This [article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/node-usage/) might help you get the metrics you want in NodeJS.

However, I don't understand why you would want to do this. I would suggest instead configuring the [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) to collect these metrics independently of any application code.

**EDIT BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION:**

You are hard coding StatisticValues. Based on the screenshot it looks like you are graphing either Sum or Minimum which you have hard coded to 5. How do you expect CloudWatch to show anything different to what you send it?

If you want to publish memory data, you need to get memory data using NodeJS by making some API/Library call e.g. [What I linked above](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/node-usage/). You then pass this value to the CloudWatch PutMetricData call...

The CloudWatch client can't magically know that because you set **MetricName=MemoryUtilization** that you want NodeJS to publish memory metrics. MetricName is just a label, it can be absolutely anything you want e.g. HowManyBeersIHadLastNight, HowLongThatPieceOfCodeTookToExecute

Also, on another note, using **StatisicValues**, i.e. a StatisticSet is a legacy and not recommended use of the CloudWatch APIs. Publishing your metrics like this prevents CloudWatch from being able to calculate rich percentiles. Either use **Value** or **Values & Counts** instead.

Comment: i have used putMetricData Api,but i was not able to get params for that correctly i think,can you help me with the StatisticValues json in params, i mean how the params should be to post memory utilization values for every 5 minutes

Comment: If you need help with code, your question should contain code and the error message you are experiencing.

Comment: yes, i have read what's given on the link you gave,but it's for the memory usage of code someones' written in nodeJs i think and not related to anything to server,right?

Comment: At this point, I think your question is getting too broad... But a quick google search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816181/get-view-memory-cpu-usage-via-nodejs